# String format to display 0 or 2 decimal places, but not 1?

Tags: c#, string, format

I want to hide the decimal places if it's 0, or show 2 if there are any.

- 1 should display as 1
- 1.05 should display as 1.05
- 1.5 should display as 1.50

Can this be accomplished with a format string, or will I just have to do something like `.ToString("0.##")` and then write code to add an extra "0" when necessary?

Comment: Yeah there is no format string that will do that.  You could use "0.00" and then if the result ends with ".00" truncate it off.

Comment: What about `1.001` or `0.9999`?

Comment: `[Number].ToString("N2").TrimEnd(".00".ToCharArray())`? What about what's asked ↑ ?

Comment: @Jimi Isn't that the same as `TrimEnd(new[] { '.', '0' })`?

Comment: @41686d6564 Exactly the same. `".00"` can be replace by a variable. The relevant part is `("N2").TrimEnd(...)`. And what @Flydog57 asked.

Comment: @Jimi What I meant is that it will not just truncate `".00"`. It will trim any `.` or `0` chars. So, `"1.50"` ends up being `"1.5"`.

Comment: @41686d6564 Sure, and `10.0001` will become `1` (that's not an answer, just a comment easy to convert to working code with a little change).

Comment: There's no built-in format that would respect your intention. You need to provide different formats depending on the value. See duplicate for how that would work (just replace the condition used there with your own based on the fractional part of the number or lack thereof, along with your own preferred format of course)

Comment: @Flydog57 Doesn't matter. I actually did start to make a note about such possibilities but then decided against mentioning it because the value I'm working with comes from a decimal (9,2) SQL column so it's irrelevant .

Comment: @Jimi I upvoted your comment before reading what the numberdnumber guy said. So it sounds like `TrimEnd(".00".ToCharArray())` and `TrimEnd(".0".ToCharArray())` are the same, neither of which would format 1.50 properly. However, as I think about it maybe instead of `TrimEnd` I could use `.Replace(".00", "")`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I also upvoted your comment, but after having read the "duplicate" and having thought to use `Replace` instead of `Trim` as Jimi mentioned, I wish I hadn't. It is a huge overgeneralization, in my opinion, to call that a duplicate *AND* there is a very simple one liner solution to this question that doesn't apply to that question. It's unfortunate that I can't add the proper answer to this question now.

Comment: @Jimi Gotcha. In this case rounding isn't an issue as the db fields only have a precision of 2 decimal places and the only math happening is to calculate a delta between forecasted and actual dollar amounts. Great points though and well worth remembering for the future so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create an extension that does it for you? You might be able to tweak it and optimize it later and can be accessed anywhere with the same results, even with intellisense.

```
public static string ToSingleOrTwoDecimals(this double source)
{
    if (source % 1 == 0) {
        return ((int) source).ToString();
    }
    
    return source.ToString("#.##");
}
```

Comment: The cast is redundant and you probably want `"0.00"` or `"#.00"`, but not `"#.##"`.

Comment: I'm marking this the answer even though I haven't tried it to see if it works properly... assuming it does though. I ended up doing something similar, except I reverse the string after converting and check for IndexOf a decimal in the 1st position, then append additional "0" if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

`String.Format(...)` is made specifically for this, and accepts a string that has special identifiers in it. [Microsoft Docs on `String.Format(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#Starting)

```cs
// Using the standard 'F2' (two places after comma) format:
var myFormattedNumber1 = String.Format("{0:F2}", 1);      // 1.00
var myFormattedNumber2 = String.Format("{0:F2}", 1.05);   // 1.05
var myFormattedNumber3 = String.Format("{0:F2}", 1.50);   // 1.50

// We can see the subtle differences when overriding the standard 'F2' format:
var myFormattedNumber4 = String.Format("{0:#.##}", 1);     // 1
var myFormattedNumber5 = String.Format("{0:#.##}", 1.05);  // 1.05
var myFormattedNumber6 = String.Format("{0:#.##}", 1.50);  // 1.5
```

Using this, you can pick your poison.